# Is there a maximum amount of pages for a multi-page post?

Tags: posts, database, performance, seo

I will publish 2 books (encyclopedia) on my site, each with over 4000 pages. My plan is to put each book into a multipage post using the

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

tag.

**1.** Can Wordpress handle such a long post? (Database, performence...)

**2.** Or is there another easy or better way to publish books in this size from a performece and SEO perspective? (Please do **not** suggest a plugin)

Comment: See [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11719495/1908141)

Comment: I wonder how the *nextpage* paging will look like for 4000 pages. If I recall correctly it shows a link to every page, so you would get 4000 links! What about one page per post (custom post type) and a custom taxonomy for chapters?

Comment: @birgie - not a bad idea... I think i will use default posts and add 10 to 20 pages to each post and put in a default category (book name) - and on the last page of the post i link to the next post with the following pages... The title of each post will have for example a "Page 1-20" addition. Hope this does not hurt SEO... What you think about that?

Answer (score 3):

If your entire page fits in the 4GB `LONGTEXT` post content field, the limit to the number of pages would be related to the amount of RAM available on your server. When a multipage post is loaded, it is exploded on `<!--nextpage-->` to put your post into an array of individual pages, so at that point your single page load is consuming at least twice the total size of the post. If that exceeds the available RAM, PHP will throw a fatal error and execution will halt.